# Посоветуйте плагин для массовой установки одного конкретного изображения записи в определенной рубрике

Tags: wordpress

Есть сайт, в котором необходимо установить одно изображение записи для определенной рубрики. Пользовался плагином Featured Image Plus, но тут для него версия php старая, а обновить ее я не могу (7.1.33).

Посоветуйте, пожалуйста, плагин со схожим функционалом. Спасибо.

Comment: Проще самому сделать, но надо знать, какая тема.

Comment: Найти такой плагин быстрее, чем писать вопросы на СО.

Comment: если я задал вопрос, наверное это вызвало у меня какую-то проблему? с таким же функционалом плагин так и не нашел, выкрутился через установку дефолтного изображения